# ActiveAdmin. Add `back` button to previous page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

How to add a button in [Active Admin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin) that behaves similar to the browser's back button.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link back to page visited before form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213176/link-back-to-page-visited-before-form)

Comment: actually its not a duplicate.. adding a Back button in active admin is not as easy as it seems

Answer (score 1):

This is a working solution i'm currently using :

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  action_item 'Back', only: :index do
    link_to('Back', :back)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I am adding this to every resource file. However, It is going in a circle. For example, If I visit the following `Users => Clients`, then if I keep clicking `Back` the browser will jump back and forth between these two pages.

Comment: Hmm, just curious. Try the same using the browser back button and see how it behaves

Comment: The browser's back button behaves differently. So `Dashboard => Users => Clients` then pressing the browser's back button would be like `Clients => Users => Dashboard` while the `action_item`'s back would go back and forth between `Clients` and `Users`