# HowTo Redirect To Index with Page after edit in Rails ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a client with a Rails 6 site running ActiveAdmin, and the client would like to return the user back to the page he or she was on in the index after selecting edit and updating a record.

For example, if a user is on the page `/admin/employees?page=2` and clicks the "Edit" link for an employee, after updating the employee record, they want to be returned back to `/admin/employees?page=2`

I've got how to return it back to the index page instead of the show page, I just can't get it to go back to page it was on.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using sessions, then following the advice here:

[Link back to page visited before form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213176/link-back-to-page-visited-before-form)

should help. To apply it to active_admin, in your `app/admin/employees.rb`, first of all save the last URL every time you hit the edit page, and then redirect to it after a successful update:

```
controller do
  def edit
    session[:my_previous_url] = URI(request.referer || '').path
    super
  end

  def update
    @employee.update(permitted_params[:employee])
    # check if the previous URL was correctly saved in session, if so use that, if not use employees index
    redirect_target = session[:my_previous_url].blank? ? employees_path : session[:my_previous_url]
    if @employee.save
      redirect_to redirect_target
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Not sure why, but my_previous_url isn't saving to the session